# Equation to get the center point of the union of n ellipses?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

If I have 3 ellipses that all intersect such as in [image: this] image.

How can I get the center point of the Union of all three ellipses?
(Basically the center point of the red area in the image)

Comment: The red area is the intersection, not union, of the ellipses

Comment: I doubt that you'll be able to do this analytically. If you want to do it numerically, you should specify the circumstances. E.g., if CPU cycles are cheap, programming time is at a premium and you don't need too much precision, you could simply generate lots of uniformly random points and average the ones that lie in all three ellipses.

Answer (score 1):

How about we reverse engineer the problem a bit, what do you say ? :-$)$ Instead of going from the equation of the ellipse$($s$)$ to determining the position of the central point, let us consider the center in question fixed at $(0,0)$, and write the equations of the three ellipses in terms of it. Let one of the two axes of symmetry of the first ellipse be the interval $(-a,b)\in\mathbb R$, with $-a<0<b$. Its center lies at $c=\dfrac{a+b}2$, and its equation is $(x-c)^2+\bigg(\dfrac yr\bigg)^2=c^2$, where $r>0$ is a parameter. Then the other two ellipses are the [rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) of the first with an angle of $\pm~\dfrac{2\pi}3$ radians. As a fun exercise, draw the $3\times3=9$ ellipses corresponding to $a=1$, $b=5$, $r\in\bigg\{\dfrac25,~1,~\dfrac74\bigg\}$ using [*Desmos*](https://www.desmos.com/calculator). :-$)$